# Oauth2 to Geoserver

Tags: google-oauth, geoserver

Is it possible to extend Google's Ouath to Geoserver's roles?  For example, a user in an RO role could make a WMS request to GeoServer using Google Oauth credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, sorry.

We have developed an OAUTH2 extension that should work with Google (and GitHub). It is available on GS 2.9.2 and 2.10.

Docs [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html)